# Connection to SQL Server from Airbyte failing: Cannot Create PoolableConnectionFactory

Tags: sql-server

I have standalone SQL Server 2019 Developer Edition installed on my machine. I am able to use pymssql to connect to it and write data in. Using this method to connect:

```py
conn = pymssql.connect(
host='my_host', 
user="airbyte_reader", 
port = 1433, 
password = '******',
database = "my_db")

#arranged like this for Stack's readability, not to infuriate people.
```

Then my Airbyte container is running on the same machine and I can see the UI on my localhost:8000. When I try to create a SQL Server source it requires

- Database
- Host
- Password
- Port
- Username

I've confirmed in SQL Server Configuration Manager that TCP/IP is enabled, and that dynamic port allocation is off, and that the static port is set to 1433. Using a user login I created I'm able to login through SQL Server Management Studio. However, when I provide Airbyte that same user, password, port, host, and database. It gives me this error message when connecting:

> Could not connect with provided configuration. Error: Cannot create
> PoolableConnectionFactory (The TCP/IP connection to the host
> my_host, port 1433 has failed. Error: "my_host. Verify the
> connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is
> running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make
> sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a
> firewall.".)

Not sure what else I can troubleshoot here, but according to the symptoms above anyone know what's going on?

(Also this is just for testing out Airbyte this isn't an actual architecture or solution)

Comment: Did you give Airbyte the username and password of your Windows account to use? Sounds like you need to create an SQL Server login for Airbyte to use instead. SQL Server logins and Windows logins use different authentication methods and aren't interchangeable.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning hey thanks for the suggestion. I just tried it out. I created a new Login, granted it sysadmin and via sql server management studio was able to login and view the table. When I gave airbyte the same credentials it still gives me an error saying the TCP/IP connection to the host has failed on port 1433 which is what the SQL Server Configuration Manager suggests it should be

Comment: Can you [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/31465841) your question to include the full and complete error message - as text? There could be important information in the error message telling you (or at least indicating) what the actual cause of the problem is.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning , yep just did. Yeah sorry that was a mess of a question before I was just burned out on trying to figure it out. Edited with fresh eyes. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is DNS resolution for `my_host` working inside the container?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn hey, sorry how can I check that? I running the container using docker-compose, I can see the port mappings for the various docker services that get spun up. But how can I check what you mentioned?

Comment: Aside... the `host` parameter for `pymssql.connect()` is undocumented. Whenever that value is supplied it is used to overwrite the `server` parameter, so just use the `server` parameter.

Comment: So just to clarify: SQL Server 2019 is installed on the Windows host machine? As opposed to inside a Docker container? Try using `server='host.docker.internal'`, Ref: [Use cases and workarounds](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/networking/#use-cases-and-workarounds).

Comment: @AlwaysLearning thanks for the suggestion, the combination of you first suggestion to create a separate user and help from a networking person in my IT solved the issue. SQL Server has a 'server name' but that wasn't for some reason being recognized by the container running Airbyte, so in the Airbyte UI I switched the name of the server to the specific IPv4 address which I got from the SQL Server Configuration Manager and that worked!

Comment: wrt. the SQL Server's host name... you may well have run afoul of Docker's default `bridge` network. User-defined bridge networks have DNS services by default, but the default `bridge` network usally needs modification. Ref: [Differences between user-defined bridges and the default bridge](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/#differences-between-user-defined-bridges-and-the-default-bridge) and [DNS Services](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#dns-services)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from @AlwaysLearning
If you have this issue, first make sure you're using a user that can authenticate via SQL Server Authentication.
Then from SQL Server Configuration Manager get the IPv4 address and use that in the field for "host" in the airbyte UI.